# Is this an idiom or is there a logical explanation?

Tags: grammar

To say "I have nothing/something to do" you say:

”Non ho niente/qualcosa da fare”.

But to say "I have nothing to do with the case" you say:

“Non ho niente/qualcosa a che fare con il caso”.

Is this merely idiomatic or is there a logic to it?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your question. What part of the second sentence seems strange to you?

Comment: @DenisNardin: I think it's the expression "aver a che fare" (which seems an idiomatic Italian expression to me). I mean, it also seemed strange to me some years ago, when I was a beginner in Italian.

Comment: Also “a che vedere”. I think the pattern used to be productive in the past, but now it's to be considered as an idiom.

Comment: The fact in itself that two phrases are similar in English and less so in Italian has nothing to be explained, in itself. Could you please explain a little better what is your question?

Comment: if you read italian, see at [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/costruzione-frase-negativa-italiano)

Comment: For your `I have nothing to do with the case`, most common is `Non ho niente a che fare con il caso`. I may say `Non ho qualcosa a che fare con il caso` as an answer to `Hai qualcosa a che fare con il caso?`, if I wish to reply with the exact nagation of the question. Bizarrely, in italian `not not p` is still `not p`.

Comment: @mario That is also true in many English dialects. The double negative is also used in some songs, which use sentences like _I can't get no satisfaction_.